# How can I test whether std::terminate is NOT called in googletest

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a custom assertion like this:

```
#define MY_ASSERT(condition, message)                                        \
do {                                                                         \
  if (!(condition)) {                                                        \
    std::cerr << "Assertion `" #condition "` failed in " << __FILE__         \
              << " line " << __LINE__ << ": " << message << std::endl;       \
    std::terminate();                                                        \
  }                                                                          \
} while (false)
```

I know that I can use Death Tests to check if assertions are called. However, I want to check whether the assertion does not actually happen. I want the specific test to actually FAIL instead of the whole application exit with code 3 because assertion failed. Here is the test that I have written:

```
TEST_F(RenderGraphDeathTest, BuildOnlyCalledOnce) {
  liquid::RenderGraph graph;

  graph.addPass<EmptyScope>(
      "A", [](auto &builder, auto &scope) { builder.write("a-b", {}); },
      noopExecutor);

  graph.compile();

  // Looking for something like EXPECT_NOT_DEATH
  graph.compile();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set a custom terminate handler in the test start. The default handler is `std::abort`. See [std::terminate_handler](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate_handler).

Comment: I tried to get it working with the terminate handler (e.g using `std:set_terminate([] { ADD_FAILURE(); });`) but nothing worked. I ended up treating using `ASSERT_EXIT` and forcing the death test to exist with 0 if there is an error.

Comment: At what point do you set the terminate handler? Googletest may reset it after you.

Comment: Right at the beginning of the test and it did not fail.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up forcefully exiting and checking the exit status code in a Death Test:

```
TEST_F(RenderGraphDeathTest, BuildOnlyCalledOnce) {
  liquid::RenderGraph graph;

  graph.addPass<EmptyScope>(
      "A", [](auto &builder, auto &scope) { builder.write("a-b", {}); },
      noopExecutor);

  ASSERT_EXIT({
    graph.compile();
    graph.compile();
    
    // If no assertion is happening,
    // this test will exit with code 0,
    // otherwise, it will exit with the
    // SIGABORT due to std::abort
    // default terminate handler
    exit(0);
  }, ::testing::ExitedWithCode(0), ".*");
}
```